# Rails Form Helpers -- Change order of inputs in DATE field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I have <%= f.date_field :day %>, which is asking users to input date in the American format: mm-dd-yyyy.

How can I change it to dd-mm-yyyy ?

While we're at it, how can I change the TIME_FIELD to ask for hours in the 24-hour system (say, instead of inputing 07:00PM, I could say 19:00)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `f.date_field` helper will create a standard (native browser) HTML input of `type='date'`

So you are not able to format the date as such, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format).

I recommend you use a jQuery plug in or date picker of some kind.